# Combine the values of different fields of json object into single array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

After making an ajax call to a certain url I am returned data in the form of a json object of the format:

```
{"feild1":["val1","val2","val3",...,"valn"],
 "feild2":["vala","valb","valc",...,"valx"]}
```

I want to combine the values of feild1 and feild2 so that I have a single array of the type :

```
["val1","val2","val3",...,"valn","vala","valb","valc",...,"valx"]
```

So I can send this single array to the response function for autocomplete. If I send `data.feild1` and then `data.feild2` then values of `data.feild2` only show up in the drop down.

Comment: Use array concat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set both arrays from your response :

```
var array1 = ["val1","val2","val3",...,"valn"];
var array2 = ["vala","valb","valc",...,"valx"];
var new_merged_array = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(new_merged_array)
```

Suppose you get the response in key `response`, then

```
var array1 = response.field1;

var array2 = response.field1;
```

Then concat both of the array using `concat` function

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the arrays to an array of arrays, and then flatten by applying [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
var data = {"feild1":["val1","val2","val3","valn"], "feild2":["vala","valb","valc","valx"]};

var result = [].concat.apply([], Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return data[key];
}));

console.log(result);
```

Or by using ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [Object#Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to extract the sub arrays:

```js
const data = {"feild1":["val1","val2","val3","valn"], "feild2":["vala","valb","valc","valx"]};

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(data));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array concat to create a single array

```
let responseArray = [];

for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    responseArray.concat(data[key]);
  }
}
```

Respond with `responseArray`

Answer (score 0):

Just use spread parameters in EcmaScript6

```
var array1 = {
  "feild1":["val1","val2","val3","valn"],              
  "feild2":["vala","valb","valc","valx"]
};

var result = [...array1.feild1, ...array1.feild2 ];
```